# How to see the volume group name of an LVM logical volume on an external Hard Drive?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk, lvm

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724), in order to shrink an encrypted partition on an external hard drive.

I think I've successfully resized the file system on that partition, and now I want to reduce the size of the LVM partition with `lvreduce`, But `sudo lvdisplay` only shows the lvm partitions of the disk from which the machine is currently booted, and not the external one (from which I am not booted, but is mounted). Same goes for `vgscan`.

How do I find the *volume group name* of the root LVM volume on the external drive?

I'd also appreciate any reference to a guide which is more appropriate to my situation (the encrypted partition is not the partition of the running operating system, and on an external hard drive).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you pass the path to that command?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I tried to pass the path of the physical device (`/dev/sdb`),  the path of the lvm volume (`/dev/mapper/luks-<a lot of numbers>`) and also the path where it is mounted (`/media/user/<FileSystemLable>`), and they all result in `Volume group "<basename from path i passed>" not found
  Cannot process volume group <basename from path i passed>`

Comment: did you use `sudo`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes, I did, with everything I tried.

Comment: Why don't you just use GUI to resize your encrypted partition? Then you don't need to worry about paths and sizes.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas Because the LVM GUI just freezes as soon as I click anything.

Comment: Which LVM GUI have you tried?

Comment: I've tried the system-config-lvm GUI.

Comment: Can you try KDE Partition Manager? system-config-lvm is not really maintained, so it's not too surprising that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$ sudo vgdisplay
```

the output includes the VG Name.

Source: https://edwards.flinders.edu.au/changing-the-volume-name-on-an-lvm-machine/